# It is safe to pass env variables( from getServerSideProps) as props to another components?

Tags: next.js

It is safe to pass env variables( from getServerSideProps) as props to another components ?

I want to use this env variable in client side but I want to be sure that it remains invisible to the client

```
const Home: NextPage = (props:any) => {
  return (      
    <HomeView priv={props.priv} />  
  );
};

export default Home;
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  return {props:{priv:process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}}
}
```

I used getServerSideProps but the env variables appear in the network tab. What can I do?
Frontend is hosted on Vercel.

Comment: 1) Screenshots are discouraged - Please copy/paste text.  2) In your example, it looks like you're writing the value into a <div> tag.  So all the user needs to do is "View, Source" in order to see the "secret"

Comment: Hi, it s a view, i try to send the value as props

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe to pass env variables from getServerSideProps as props to another component. It is safe because env variables are securely stored on the server and cannot be accessed from the client side. This means that the data is not exposed to potentially malicious actors, ensuring that it remains secure.

If you want to use the env variable on the client side but remain invisible to the client, then you can use a server-side environment variable store such as dotenv or Vault to store the variable securely and access it on the server side. This will prevent the variable from being exposed to the client.

You can also use the Node.js global object process.env to securely store environment variables and access them on the server side. For example:

```js
// server-side
const MY_SECRET_VARIABLE = process.env.MY_SECRET_VARIABLE;
// client-side
const MY_SECRET_VARIABLE = null;
```

Comment: Better reply: "No, it's *ONLY* safe if you pass the env variable to another back-end component, or take special steps to ensure the server-side variable is *NEVER* visible to the client".

Comment: I used getServerSideProps but the env variables appear in the network tab. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Environment secrets like private keys should not be passed to the client at all. Instead, you should use them server-side in API functions or getServerSideProps.

If you have an environment variable that isn't secret or is needed by a 3rd party script such as analytics, you can use the [NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser). This will inline the secret into the bundle at build time.